# WebClient is stripping newlines from files when using DownloadFile

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Using this code to download any type of plain text file (cpp, txt, etc), the WebClient is stripping the newlines out of the text file. Is there a way to force the WebClient to treat the text file as binary? I am downloading many other files using the same WebClient, and most of them are not text, just a few.

```
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var wc = new GZipWebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
            wc.DownloadFile(@"link", "test.txt");
        }
    }

    class GZipWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            return request;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `the WebClient is stripping the newlines out of the text file` no it doesn't.

Comment: I would be *astonished* to find it was doing this. My guess is that the original source code doesn't have the kind of line breaks your operating system expects...

Comment: Use Fiddler to verify, that indeed WebClient is functioning correctly. Then, look elsewhere.

Comment: I was using FileZilla on Windows for FTP transfer. I wrote the test file in Notepad, then tried sending it as binary. This preserved the newlines. I then tried on the auto transfer setting, and when I downloaded it again it was missing the newlines. I guess FileZilla changes the new lines to Unix, and then WebClient preserved that, so viewing it in Notepad, the file still had Unix endings

Answer (score 2):

I think you're viewing the downloaded file in notepad.  Try another editor.